# Polars: settings not to display ellipsis

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-polars

Polars chops some text instead of showing all text like the following

| Link | Name |
| --- | --- |
| https://... | name1 |
| https://... | name2 |

I want Polars to show all text of `Link` Col

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change `pl.Config()` settings - `pl.Config.set_fmt_str_lengths(n)` ([see doc](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Config.set_fmt_str_lengths.html))

```py
import polars as pl
pl.Config.set_fmt_str_lengths(50)


df = pl.DataFrame({"n": [1], "link": ["https://stackoverflow.com/long/link"]})
print(df)
```

```
┌─────┬─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ n   ┆ link                                │
│ --- ┆ ---                                 │
│ i64 ┆ str                                 │
╞═════╪═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ https://stackoverflow.com/long/link │
└─────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

---

If you just want to check, how new table view looks like, you can use `with pl.Config()` (this will not affect to next table's printings). Also `pl.Config.set_tbl_width_chars(n)` allows to set total width of table. For instance:

```py
with pl.Config() as cfg:
    cfg.set_tbl_width_chars(15) # total width of table
    cfg.set_fmt_str_lengths(50)
    print(df)
```

```
┌─────┬───────┐
│ n   ┆ link  │
│ --- ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ str   │
╞═════╪═══════╡
│ 1   ┆ https │
│     ┆ ://st │
│     ┆ ackov │
│     ┆ erflo │
│     ┆ w.com │
│     ┆ /long │
│     ┆ /link │
└─────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Thanks! I wonder what's the diff between `set_tbl_width_chars` and `set_fmt_str_lengths`.

Comment: `set_tbl_width_chars` defines total width (number of characters) of the entire table. See example in the answer.